# Replace strings in all dataframe cells by corresponding entries in another data frame

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe with a differing number of names in a cell of a dataframe which I want to replace with corresponding numbers of another dataframe. Afterwards, I want to proceed and calculate the mean and maximum but thats not part of my problem.

```
df_with_names <-read.table(text="
id names
1 AA,BB
2 AA,CC,DD
3 BB,CC
4 AA,BB,CC,DD
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

The dataframe with the correspoding numbers looks like

```
df_names <-read.table(text="
name number_1 number_2
AA 20 30
BB 12 14
CC 13 29
DD 14 27
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

At the end of the first step it should be

```
id number_1   number_2
1 20,12       30,14
2 20,13,14    30,29,27
3 12,13       14,29
4 20,12,13,14 30,14,29,27
```

From here I know how to proceed but I don't know how to get there.

I tried to separate the names of each row in a loop into a dataframe and then replace the names but I always fail to get the right column of `df_with_names`. After a while, I doubt that `replace()` is the function I am looking for. Who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

dt1 = as.data.table(df_with_names)
dt2 = as.data.table(df_names)

setkey(dt2, name)

dt2[setkey(dt1[, strsplit(as.character(names), split = ","), by = id], V1)][,
    lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse = ","), keyby = id]
#   id        name    number_1    number_2
#1:  1       AA,BB       20,12       30,14
#2:  2    AA,CC,DD    20,13,14    30,29,27
#3:  3       BB,CC       12,13       14,29
#4:  4 AA,BB,CC,DD 20,12,13,14 30,14,29,27
```

The above first splits the names along the comma in the first `data.table`, then joins that with the second one (after setting keys appropriately) and collapses all of the resulting columns back with a comma.

Comment: This looks very short and is extremely fast. Albeit I don't understand what's happening here since except for the sorting.

Comment: @user3621464 try running each piece separately - and if some part is unclear feel free to ask about it

Answer (score 2):

Another all in one:

```
data2match <- strsplit(df_with_names$names, ',')

lookup <- function(lookfor, in_df, return_col, search_col=1) {
  in_df[, return_col][match(lookfor, in_df[, search_col])]
}

output <- 
  # for each number_x column....
  sapply(names(df_names)[-1],
         function(y) {
           # for each set of names
           sapply(data2match,
                  function(x) paste(sapply(x, lookup, df_names, 
                                  y, USE.NAMES=F), collapse=','))
         })

data.frame(id=1:nrow(output), output)
```

Produces:

```
  id    number_1    number_2
1  1       20,12       30,14
2  2    20,13,14    30,29,27
3  3       12,13       14,29
4  4 20,12,13,14 30,14,29,27
```

Comment: +1 for that lookup function. Reminds me of Excel's lookup functions.

Answer (score 0):

Note: make sure both dataframes are ordered by id otherwise you may see unexpected results

```
listing <- df_with_names
listing <- strsplit(as.character(listing$names),",")

col1 <- lapply(listing, function(x) df_names[(df_names[[1]] %in% x),2])
col2 <- lapply(listing, function(x) df_names[(df_names[[1]] %in% x),3])

col1 <- unlist(lapply(col1, paste0, collapse = ","))
col2 <- unlist(lapply(col2, paste0, collapse = ","))

data.frame(number_1 = col1, number_2 = col2 )

     number_1    number_2
1       20,12       30,14
2    20,13,14    30,29,27
3       12,13       14,29
4 20,12,13,14 30,14,29,27
```

Comment: There is no variable `id` for the dataset with the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like names like "names" or "name", so I went with "nam":

```
 do.call( rbind,    # reassembles the individual lists
    apply(df_with_names, 1,   # for each row in df_with_names
          function(x)  lapply(   #  lapply(..., paste) to each column
             # Next line will read each comma separated value and 
             # and match to rows of df_names[] and return cols 2:3
               df_names[ df_names$nam %in% scan(text=x[2], what="", sep=",") ,
                       2:3, drop=FALSE] ,   # construct packet of text digits
                                paste0, collapse=",") ) )


     number_1      number_2     
[1,] "20,12"       "30,14"      
[2,] "20,13,14"    "30,29,27"   
[3,] "12,13"       "14,29"      
[4,] "20,12,13,14" "30,14,29,27"
```

(I'm surprised that scan(text= ... a factor variable actually succeeded.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would actually be worth your while to rearrange your `df_with_names` dataset to make things more straight-forward:

```
spl <- strsplit(as.character(df_with_names$names), ",")
df_with_names <- data.frame(
  id=rep(df_with_names$id, sapply(spl, length)),
  name=unlist(spl)
)

#   id name
#1   1   AA
#2   1   BB
#3   2   AA
#4   2   CC
#5   2   DD
#6   3   BB
#7   3   CC
#8   4   AA
#9   4   BB
#10  4   CC
#11  4   DD

aggregate(
  . ~ id,
  data=merge(df_with_names, df_names, by="name")[-1],
  FUN=function(x) paste(x,collapse=",")
)

#  id    number_1    number_2
#1  1       20,12       30,14
#2  2    20,13,14    30,29,27
#3  3       12,13       14,29
#4  4 20,12,13,14 30,14,29,27
```

Comment: Runs very good - the only thing I don't like about is that I have to write every name of a variable containing numbers (`number_1, number_2`) by myself. If the names vary with the dataset or if they are many you have additional effort.

Comment: @user3621464 - you can get around this - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
df3 = data.frame(id=df1$id, 
                 number_1=as.character(df1$names), 
                 number_2=as.character(df1$names), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(n1 in 1:nrow(df3))
    for(n2 in 1:nrow(df2)){
            df3[n1,2] = sub(df2[n2,1],df2[n2,2], df3[n1,2] )   
            df3[n1,3] = sub(df2[n2,1],df2[n2,3], df3[n1,3] )   
    }

df3
#  id    number_1    number_2
#1  1       20,12       30,14
#2  2    20,13,14    30,29,27
#3  3       12,13       14,29
#4  4 20,12,13,14 30,14,29,27
```